# Reverse engineering the "Target Display Mode" on an iMac

Tags: linux, macos, reverse-engineering

I have a computer lab with a couple of old-ish iMacs (around 2011). Most people now just want to use them as displays for their laptops, and with Target Display Mode in MacOS, this (mostly) works fine.

However, I'd also like to support this under Linux, which is installed on all the iMacs in parallel to MacOS. I'm fairly experienced with the Linux kernel (I already wrote kernel drivers), but I have basically no idea about MacOS - therefore, I'm looking for pointers regarding how to figure out how TDM is actually triggered (i.e. what happens *after* Cmd-F2 is pressed).

I'm guessing this mostly involves writing some Intel GPU registers, but I have no idea which bit of MacOS is actually responsible for that. Any hints?

Comment: Apparently, the dpd process  (DisplayPort Daemon, see https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dpd.8.html ) is responsible. So I'll dig in that direction next...

Comment: Next update: looks like the SMC is responsible for controlling TDM, at least on the pre-Thunderbolt models (see https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1030?locale=en_US).

Comment: Of course Apple couldn't just expose the DisplayPort input as a regular display when the computer is off or some switch is flipped… \*smh\*

Comment: Whoever downvoted this is shouldn't be anywhere near here.  Great work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So I figured it out on my own after all. After looking at libsmc, SMCKit, smc_util and the applesmc driver, I found that writing 0x02 to SMC key "MVMR" will cause the display to switch to DisplayPort input.

For details, see my short blog post: **https://floe.butterbrot.org/matrix/hacking/tdm/**

Tools are on Github: https://github.com/floe/smc_util

Comment: Could you explain how to "write 0x02 to SMC key NVMR"? I am not very familiar with all the low level mac stuff - still, I was trying to get this to work on my (late) 2009 iMac. It *should* support target display mode - but it does not seem to be working. I read through your blog post (very interesting :)) and ran some of the scripts that you linked to - but it still did not work :(. I was looking through some of the git repos that you mentioned but I still could not find a way to write to the SMC. I would appreciate any help you can give me - thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're working under Linux - did you already compile SmcDumpKey from https://github.com/floe/smc_util ? What happens when you run `SmcDumpKey MVMR`?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I read your blog post, but I'm not sure I follow the entire story. I compiled your program and tried running, but I get an error when I try running SmcDumpKey (which I compiled with the lines in the beginning of the code). The error is the following (I am explicitly putting the \n because the comments here remove the line breaks): ```$ sudo ./SmcDumpKey MVMR\n
send_byte(0x13, 0x0304) fail: 0xff\n
MVHR: read arg fail\n
\n
read_smc get_key_type error\n
```
I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: I ran this from my Linux computer (not sure if I was supposed to run this in the iMac).

Comment: @vaulttech: this will only run on the iMac _while_ it is running Linux. If you're only running MacOS on the iMac, then you don't need it at all. For the computer that's supposed to be the DisplayPort _source_, no special treatment is needed.

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party, but hoping you can help me out. When I run SmcDumpKey MVMR from my ubuntu install I get this:
usdo ./SmcDumpKey MVMR
send_byte(0x06, 0x0300) fail: 0x10
MVMR: read len fail

read_smc get_key_type error

Comment: @NickS this is to be expected, I think it's a race condition with the `applesmc` kernel driver (which is autoloaded). It still works when you write a byte to MVMR as in the example script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the tdm_on.sh but I just get similar errors, my monitor flickers black, and then comes back. I'm sure I'm missing something basic. I'll try to take a closer look at the source code if I can get the children in bed on time tonight :)

Comment: Thanks @FlorianEchtler ... I was just starting to get my hands dirty to take on the same quest ... I got as far as libexec/dpd which led me here.  Freaking happy that I don't need a stupid keyboard plugged in for this to work... Great stuff.

Comment: @FlorianEchtler ah i take it all back ... the tools don't even compile on mac

Comment: OK, could you open an issue on Github? Should be easier to discuss there.

Comment: does anyone here have any links as how to do this on a Mac? See here for what I am trying to investigate more.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254538589?answerId=258479648022&cid=em-com-apple_watches_email_thread_owner-view_the_full_discussion-en-us-11192020#258479648022

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delete - sorry, absolutely no idea for the Thunderbolt-based Macs. All I can suggest is to use smc_util and have a look at the various SMC keys (but that may not work anymore on more recent versions of macOS).